# Plugin to alter custom attribute value

Tags: magento2, after-plugin

To alter product price before displaying on frontend we can use Plugin `afterGetPrice()` same for Name `afterGetName` and so on for default product attributes.

Is there any way to perform same for any custom product attribute?